# Запуск диалоговых окон из потока, при закрытом приложении

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Имеется приложение. При запуске приложения запускается сервис. В сервисе запускается поток. В потоке идет работа. Когда в потоке нужна реакция от пользователя (ввести значение) необходимо вывести диалоговое окно. Получить результат ввода и получить его в потоке, который вызвал это окно.

Я не знаю какие объекты использовать и как организовать эту последовательность действий. Вызвать диалоговое окно из активити я могу. Но как открыть его из потока не представляю. Так же необходимо, что бы окно выходило даже если приложение закрыто(работает сервис) или было открыто другое сообщение.

Мне совсем не нужно готовое решение, прошу подсказать хотя бы приблизительный алгоритм и/или какие классы использовать.

UPD 1: Я нашел способ отобразить диалоговое окно из потока. Класс `android.os.Handler` предоставляет необходимый функционал. Описывать процесс не буду, т.к. довольно легко найти информацию в интернете или на худой конец задать вопрос.

Но есть небольшая проблема. Диалоговое окно открывается только, если открыто именно то активити, которое было передано в конструкторе `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`. Т.е. даже в другом окне моего же приложения диалоговое окно не появляется. А желательно было бы, что бы открылось в любом случае, что бы пользователь не делал (экран потух, пользователь в другом приложении, или на рабочем столе).

На данный момент интересуют вопросы:

Приостановка потока (в котором был вызван handler) до получения реакции пользователя. Думаю в сторону handler callback.

Вывод диалогового окна в любом случае, что бы не делал пользователь.

Comment: Вы загнали себя в рамки конкретной реализации на уровне "сервис-поток", не подумав в целом об архитектуре. Можно все, и handler прикрутить (самое простое, но его одного недостаточно, конечно) и broadcatsreceiver и стартовать activity из сервиса и т.д. Но это такие костыли и макароны. Учитывая предыдущие ваши вопросы, алгоритм у вас получается методом тыка-затыка. Вполне возможно, что задача ваша решается более простым методом, пахнет xy-проблемой...

Comment: Может быть правильней будет сделать через нотификации? По тапу которой будет открываться активити с вводом данных. Диалог как-то не хорошо смотрится

Comment: Я посмотрю и нотификации. Был бы у меня опыт, более чем 1 недописанное приложение. Об архитектуре же я начну задумываться после как смогу решать 80-90% поставленных задач без постоянного гугления неизвестной фукнкции или класса или задавая регулярно вопросы. Алгоритмы тыка-затыка, костыли и макороны пока увы будут, и в большом количестве. Но... давайте решать проблемы по мере их поступления :)

Comment: да я могу это быстренько накрутить, но пользователю очень не понравится, если он сидит к примеру смотрит видос или листает ленту, и тут вылетает непонятный диалог и еще ждет ввода каких-то данных, думаю 99% пользователей посмотрит что это за приложение, и хлопнет его - в лучшем случае, меньшая часть не полениться, зайдет в маркет и напишет гнусный отзыв, а бот Google пройдется по тегам и также быстренько ваше приложение закроют, остается только скрестить пальчики, чтоб акк туда же в трубу не полетел. Но ещё раз, по сути я могу  написать, но решение - нотификации и поле ввода прям оттуда.

Answer (score 2):

Приложение может выполнять `startActivity()` не только из activity, но и из service. Единственное отличие -- должен быть указан флаг `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. Например:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourDialogActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("data", "some additional data, if you need");
startActivity(intent);
```

Это activity может быть маленьким, как диалоговое окно (собственно, диалоговые окна так и делаются), для этого в манифесте к описанию этой activity достаточно добавить

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"
```

Об этом есть статья с примерами и разными стилями: http://jollydroid.ru/notebook/2016-09-21-Small-Window-Theme.html

Comment: Жаль, но ссылка на статью с примерами уже не работает.